# Function with constant as an argument

Tags: vba, parameter-passing, constants, intellisense

Some predefined VBA methods and functions require that a specific constant be passed to them, e.g.:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
.cells(i,j).End(xlUp).Row
.PpParagraphAlignment = ppAlignCenter
```

In these snippets, the constants are *xlCalculationAutomatic*, *xlUp* and *ppAlignCenter*.

When the function/method is called and one is asked to populate the argument, VBE Intellisense is typically offering a dropdown of the valid constants to select from.

Is there a way to achieve the same thing with my own subroutines and functions? E.g. in the below case, the argument "sRowOrCol" requires the user currently to type in the literals "Row" or "Col", however I would like to offer the user a dropdown containing e.g. "xlRow" and "xlCol".

```
Function FindLast(ws As Worksheet, sRowOrCol As String, iColRow As Long)
    If sRowOrCol = "Row" Then
        FindLast = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, iColRow).End(xlUp).Row
        Exit Function
    ElseIf sRowOrCol = "Col" Then
        FindLast = ws.Cells(iColRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Exit Function
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid argument"
    End If    
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you’re looking for the [`Enum` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/enum-statement). In your case, it could look like this:

```vb
Enum Margin
    Row
    Column
End Enum

' …

Function FindLast(ws As Worksheet, margin As Margin, iColRow As Long)
    If margin = Row Then
    …
End Function
```

IntelliSense will work with this but you might want to give your enum constants a common prefix (e.g. `mar`) to facilitate their selection in the IntelliSense DropDown box. That’s why e.g. `xlUp` has the prefix `xl`. Though personally I’m not a big fan of such prefixes.

Comment: `If m = Margin.Row Then` also works and looks better IMO. It does not work in your example because you [named the argument after the type](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/212772/30872) which confuses intellisense.

Comment: This seems to work. Probably for the sake of the answer, it would be worth noting that the Enum statement is stand-alone piece of code independent from any Subroutine/Function.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could also use the Excel-Enum XlRowCol:

It looks like you're also missing 'or' in If sRow__Col = "Row" Then

```
Function FindLast(ws As Worksheet, sRowOrCol As XlRowCol, iColRow As Long)
    If sRowOrCol = xlRows Then
        FindLast = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, iColRow).End(xlUp).Row
        Exit Function
    ElseIf sRowOrCol = xlCols Then
        FindLast = ws.Cells(iColRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Exit Function
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid argument"
    End If
End Function
```

initially I only changed the part which had to be changed, to make it easier for OP; completed adjusted code:

```
Function FindLast(ws As Worksheet, RowOrCol As XlRowCol, ColRow As Long) As Long
    Select Case RowOrCol
        Case xlRows: FindLast = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ColRow).End(xlUp).Row
        Case xlColumns: FindLast = ws.Cells(ColRow, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Case Else: MsgBox "Invalid RowOrCol argument"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Using Polish Notation is bad enough as it is but it’s even worse to use the wrong type hints. ;-)

Comment: You mean Hungarian notation? I just left the OP's code unchanged ;-)

Comment: Err yes, exactly. Point is, that’s part fo the code that *needs* to be changed.

Comment: I noticed that once modifying the code. I have no idea how the function worked...

Comment: @EvR There are reasons for that notation:)